# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error in call to cellForItemAtIndexPath()

Tags: ios, swift

My code is crashing with the following error in the line that gets the cell at the index path and I'm having trouble debugging it.

> Thread: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)

```
var cell = CollectionViewCell()

for row in 0...self.collectionNetList.count {
   let indexpath = NSIndexPath.init(forRow: row, inSection: 0)

   self.cell = collectionView?.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexpath) as! CollectionViewCell 

   // ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑ CRASHES HERE ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑

   cell.dlImage.image=UIImage(named: "ted")  //Modify the custom pictures on the cell
}
```

However in this method the same instruction works as expected.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as! CollectionViewCell
}
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question in there, in addition, the formatting seems to be so poor that it's unclear what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Have you connected IBOutlet of cell.dlImage? And please formate your question properly... As it is not 100% understandable

Comment: cell.dlImage In a custom cell

Comment: Have you tried using the XCode debugger to set a break point right before that line and verify that the indexPath is valid and that collectionView references a still-valid CollectionView? For example if it's non-null, but has a stale or corrupted value, the "?" won't help. Also clearer in your code if you declare `var cell : CollectionViewCell`, rather than initialize it to an *instance* of CollectionViewCell, because you discard the instance in the loop anyway, so it just wastes CPU time to construct an instance of the class you don't use.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
    let aCell = cell as! CollectionViewCell
  aCell.dlImage.image=UIImage(named: "ted")
}
```

Such a right

Answer (score 0):

CollectionViewCell is not registered.  You need to call registerNib method of UICollectionView to register the custom cell in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear method.

Comment: override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
     self.collectionView?.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
    }
No or collapsed
self.cell=collectionView?.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexpath) as!        CollectionViewCell